# What is the maximum value of $\frac{2x}{x + 1} + \frac{x}{x - 1}$, if $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x > 1$?

Tags: calculus, inequality, functional-inequalities

What is the maximum value of
$$f(x) = \frac{2x}{x + 1} + \frac{x}{x - 1},$$
if $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $x > 1$?

A 2-D plot of of $f$ for $x \in (\infty, \infty)$ is [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Graph+%28%282x%29%2F%28x+%2B+1%29+%2B+%28x%2F%28x+-+1%29%29%29).

Lastly, note that [WolframAlpha cannot find a global maximum](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Maximize+%28%282x%29%2F%28x+%2B+1%29+%2B+%28x%2F%28x+-+1%29%29%29%2C+x+%3E+1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x>1$ we have $f(x)>\frac1{x-1}$, which is unbounded from above.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:** Use the derivative test. If you differentiate the function and equate to zero you get the two critical points

> $$ 3+2\sqrt{2},\, 3-2\sqrt{2}. $$

Now, find the second derivative to test the critical points.

Comment: @JoseArnaldoDris: You are welcome.

Comment: Oops, an error message "Comments can only be edited for 5 minutes" came up while I was trying to edit my previous comment.  My apologies to you @Mhenni Benghorbal.

Comment: Here is a gist of the comment that I intended to edit previously:

"Thanks @Mhenni Benghorbal!  Following your hint:

The first derivative is:

$$g(x) = \frac{d}{dx}f(x) = \frac{x^2 - 6x + 1}{(x^2 - 1)^2}$$

while the second derivative is:

$$h(x) = \frac{d}{dx}g(x) = -\frac{2(x^3 - 9x^2 + 3x - 3)}{(x^2 - 1)^3}."$$

Comment: Using the derivative test, there is a local minimum at

$$x = 3 + 2\sqrt{2}$$

and there is a local maximum at

$$x = 3 - 2\sqrt{2}.$$

In particular, $y = f(x)$ has no global maximum for $x > 1$.  =)

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

Let $$y=\frac{2x}{x+1}+\frac x{x-1}$$

$$\implies x^2(3-y)-x+y=0$$

which is a quadratic equation in $x$

For real $x,$ the discriminant must be $\ge0$

Comment: Thanks @lab bhattacharjee!  Following your hint, I get

$$y \geq \frac{1}{2}\left(3 + 2\sqrt{2}\right).$$

In particular, this shows (as Hagen von Eitzen has already pointed out) that $y = f(x)$ is unbounded from above.

Comment: @JoseArnaldoDris, the function also does not have any minimum for real $x$

Comment: Yes indeed.  The 2-D plot from WolframAlpha does show that.  =)